# recipe.rb + attributes.rb isn't working

Tags: chef-infra

I am totally new to chef and try to acustom myself to it.

I've already written some recipes which do work but I've always put the attributes into the recipes itself. Now I am trying to seperate attributes and recipes but it won't work in any way I try and I don't know what I do wrong...

I created a cookbook in C:\chef-repo\ vie "chef generate coobook ff_test" then I created an attribute.rb via "chef generate attribute ff_test\ default".
Now I have a folder structure where default.rb is in attributes and an other default.rb is in recipes.

```
#attributes\default.rb 
# Cookbook Name:: ff_test
# Attribute:: default

default['firefox']['version'] = 'latest'
default['firefox']['lang'] = 'de-DE'
default['firefox']['url'] = 'https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/'
```

Now, when I try to access these attributes within my other default.rb which looks like this

```
#recipes\default.rb
# Cookbook Name:: ff_test
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright (c) 2015 The Authors, All Rights Reserved.


ruby_block "test1" do
  block do
    puts "#{node['firefox']['url']}"
  end
end
```

via "chef-apply recipes\default.rb" I get the following output...

```
$ chef-apply recipes/default.rb
Recipe: (chef-apply cookbook)::(chef-apply recipe)
  * ruby_block[test1] action run

    - execute the ruby block test1
```

As you can see, nothing gets put out....

Oh, I use Chef: 12.4.1 on Windows 8.1

Comment: "then I created an attribute.rb" I mean attributes\default.rb

Comment: You might want to test with chef log vs Ruby's 'puts': https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html  Also, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your usage of attributes / recipes.  You might just do 'puts "foo"' or something to make sure that its behaving the way you want it to.

Comment: `chef-apply` is meant to run **only** standalone recipes. It does not load a cookbook in any way, so your atrtibute file is nerver read. Try `chef-solo -o my_cookbook` assuming the cookbook is in the cookbook_path of your knife.rb or client.rb.

Comment: @Tensibai 
 
$ chef-solo -o ff_test/ (...) [2015-09-10T16:08:26+02:00] WARN: Did not find config file: C:\chef\solo.rb, using command line options. my installation is in C:\opscode\chef (and chef-dk) do i have to adjust the path ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd better read the [docs](http://docs.chef.io) and http://learn.chef.io/ for this

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_apply.html) says:

> chef-apply is an executable program that runs a single recipe from the command line

The attributes/default.rb is never included because it is not a recipe, or part of a recipe.  It is a cookbook component.  To test a cookbook you need to use something that compiles a cookbook like chef-zero, chef-server/chef-client, etc.